# Knowing which ethernet driver I need

Tags: windows, drivers, ethernet

I am trying to install Windows XP on my machine, but have misplaced my nVidia nForce 630i CD (I never needed it before). Now after installation, I used my Mac to download the latest drivers and install them. Weirdly, Windows says that the ethernet driver is not the one for the computer.

Can anyone tell me how I can extract more information to troubleshoot this. It's driving me crazy! :( If you need any code or IRQ settings, I'll gladly provide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF this is built in to the motherboard, the best and quickest thing you can do is just to turn on the machine and look for the motherboard model number in the bios, or startup flash screen.

(if you are unsure, it can be done in Windows through a WMI script, but I cannot quickly find it, if you want this method, write in comments and I will try to dig it up).

Google the model number or go to the manufacturers website, and you should be able to find the correct drivers that work for your motherboard.

Generally you can go to Nvidia's, Realtek;s e.t.c. website and download drivers directly, but if you are unsure on exact model numbers, the easiest and most guaranteed solution is just to use the original driver from the motherboard manufacturer and then update through Windows Update.

Comment: +1. The motherboard's model number is usually the best way to quickly identify the other components on it, especially onboard devices like the sound card and NICs.

Comment: +1 this was great. Thank you. :) Found out and downloaded. :)

Answer (score 2):

a good tip that will always work simply :

download and burn a linux live cd (Slitaz or Ubuntu)

run on the live cd and open the terminal then type :

lspci (to see all stuff linked in your computer)

lsusb (to see all stuff connected on usb ports)

... (there still many easy way like dmesg, lshw, ...)

Answer (score 1):

download and run **[SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/download/siw.exe)** (standalone, English)

in the left hand column, under **Hardware**, click **Motherboard** to identify make and model, then download the driver from the mainboard manufacturer's website.

or click **PCI** and identify make and model of the ethernet controller, then download the driver from the supplier's website (e.g. Broadcom, Intel).

Comment: Ooh, this looks like a good utility. :) Definitely gonna keep this software handy! Thanks. I'll +1 as soon as I'm 15rep.

Comment: one of these little 'must have' utilities for your USB toolkit :)

Comment: yup, totally! :D

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you may have selected the wrong OS when you downloaded the driver or that the download page auto-selected OS X since you were on a Mac. I would try downloading it again and make sure that the selection matches the target machine's OS exactly.

Comment: Hi Dennis, nope. Being a motherboard driver (can't do that on macs..) I selected Windows XP 32bit, which is what I installed.